# Short question about key of Hill Cipher

Tags: cryptography

Is the key of Hill cipher for example for $m=2$, the determinant always an odd number?

Because when I try to make a key and the determinant is even number, I can't find the inverse in modulo 26.

Comment: Hint: If $a$ is invertible mod $b$, $a$ and $b$ must be coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant must be odd and not 13.  This is because of the fact that a matrix with entries mod $n$ is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible mod $n$.  Since the only invertible elements mod 26 are the odds except 13, the same must be required of your determinant.